# Overfitting problem: high accurance and low accurancy validation for image classification

Tags: tensorflow, image-classification, overfitting

I want to define a model to predict 3 categories of images. I'm learnong on the field :-)
I've 1500 images (500 for each category) in 3 directories. I've read in this blog many suggestions:

- use a simple loss function
- use droput
- use shuffle

I've applied these tricks but the model still overfits ...
This is the code I'm using, any suggestion?

```
dim_x = 500
dim_y = 200
dim_kernel = (3,3)

data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255,validation_split=0.3)
data_dir = image_path

train_data_generator=data_gen.flow_from_directory( 
    data_dir,
    target_size=(dim_x,dim_y),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training')

validation_data_generator=data_gen.flow_from_directory( 
    data_dir,
    target_size=(dim_x,dim_y),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=dim_kernel,input_shape=(dim_x, dim_y, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.40))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=dim_kernel,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.20))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')

class MyThresholdCallback(Callback):

    def __init__(self, threshold):
        super(MyThresholdCallback, self).__init__()
        self.threshold = threshold

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None): 
        val_accuracy = logs["val_accuracy"]
        accuracy = logs["accuracy"]
        if (accuracy >= self.threshold) and (val_accuracy>self.threshold):
            self.model.stop_training = True
mtc=MyThresholdCallback(0.8)

model.fit(
    train_data_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=10,
    epochs=40,
    validation_data=validation_data_generator,
    validation_steps=10,
    shuffle=True
    ,callbacks=[mtc]
    )
```

Here below the history

```
    loss    accuracy    val_loss    val_accuracy
0   35.930771   0.300000    1.096471    0.3875
1   1.510384    0.337500    1.099458    0.2750
2   1.104813    0.362500    1.098945    0.3000
3   1.104424    0.475000    1.098440    0.3125
4   1.110834    0.325000    1.099410    0.2750
5   1.086059    0.500000    1.092703    0.4125
6   1.019856    0.575000    1.098669    0.3125
7   0.970792    0.575000    1.081574    0.4125
8   0.939478    0.625000    1.062269    0.3750
9   0.758962    0.675000    1.197168    0.4125
10  0.624016    0.775000    1.015282    0.3750
11  0.508740    0.862500    1.300160    0.3500
12  0.430987    0.851351    1.648522    0.2875
37  0.003358    1.000000    3.144989    0.2875
38  0.011525    1.000000    3.506971    0.2125
39  0.010525    1.000000    3.989878    0.3125
```

Answer (score 1):

It is normal. Overfitting always happens when you have a model complex enough and trained long enough. In your case, I'd say it starts after ~5 epochs.

There are a few things you can do:

1. Apply early stopping, i.e. stop the training after ~5 epochs. There are some [off-the-shelf implementation](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/) which shall replace `MyThresholdCallback`.
2. If you are not satisfy with the accuracy, try lower the learning rate / get more data / tune hyper-parameters / try other architectures etc.. This is the general approach and a lot of things to try.

Comment: Hi Ipounng, thank you for your answer. just some questions about it: How can I set a a "lower learning rate? Plz can you explain better it? Which parameter I've to tune?

Comment: @ipounng, do you have any feedback on last questions? Tx in adv

Comment: The learning rate goes with optimizer, which is `Adam` in your case. You can check the tunable parameters from [doc of Adam](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/adam/)